# SSIS package works properly in visual studio but hangs after deploy (some records inserted then crashed)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, crash, business-intelligence

I have 5 sql servers as a source and one Oracle database as a Data wareHouse (destination).
3 of them (sources) works properly in VS and also after deployed. but 2 of them works properly in VS but failed in IntegrationServices after some records inserted!.

SSIS server config:

- 4GB ram
- 64 bit windows server 2008 r2
- cpu xeon 2.30 GHz (2 processors)
- there are 778280 records in the source.
- buffer size in SSIS (and other configs) set to default values.

the package runs properly in the visual studio but after deploying to the IntegrationServices and executing ,it crashes after inserting about 333900 (some time 333500, and sometimes 334100, ...) records , with these error messages:

> [PACKAGE NAME]:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error Code: 0x90050E2F,
>   An OLE DB record is available. Source: "OraOLEDB" Hresult: 0x80040E2F Description: "Value violated the integrity constraints for a column or table".
>
> [PACKAGE NAME]:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INCLUDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row diposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

as u can see, it tells *"Value violated the integrity constraints ......"*
but:

1. there are no constraints in the destination (no PK, no Unique index, nothing)
2. the package runs properly in VS!!! (and all of 778280 records inserted into destination!!) so there is no integrity constraint violation happened (or memory limitation)!
3. I tested for many input ranges to see if some records in the source has errors. ie: i sort the input descending, ascending, sort by different column,... and in all of them, only about 334100 (or something like that) records inserted in the destination and then crashed.
4. I double checked 32/64 bit package properties to sure about that.

---

I changed the query to a simple one-column query to check if any column's value are responsible for this fault:
`SELECT 1 as 'PayPrice' FROM Cash`

as u can see, there's only one column with 1 value. and there's about 800000 records in the source. but after inserting about 563810 records, the same error happened and the package execution failed.

and (i'm surprised) sometimes this message shown (and the package execution status changed to "Unexpected termination" :
[memory?!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPDF0.jpg)

so the question is: 
whats happened in the IntegrationServices?
Is there any limitation (memory-related,...) in my scenario?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are VS and SSIS executing on the same machine?

Comment: yeah the same machine..to check if any specified columns is responsible for integrity constraint violation, I just use this query: 
"SELECT    1 as 'PayPrice'FROM   Cash" 

as u can see, only a repeated 1 value (and about 800000 records), and the same error raised again after 532600  inserted